# Is there a shortcut to create a throwaway HTML project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

Whenever I want to try something in html/js/css, I create a new folder, fire up Visual Studio Code, then create index.html, app.css, script.js and favicon.ico (so devtools in Firefox don't complain).  I create boilerplate html via Emmet (!), link css and js and start work.

I've done this countless times.  Is there a shortcut or a plugin that will create a boilerplate project like this for me?

P.S.  I do have a boilerplate that I copy.  However, I'd like a template driven system that lets me replace a couple of things.  Kind of like what's possible in Visual Studio proper.

Comment: Why not make that your boilerplate. Call the folder "boilerplate" and then just copy/paste it ready for a new project.

Comment: @Andy I've done that before.  I was hoping to omit that step and create a project from a template (particularly if I need to change name or some params) like in Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cantonios.project-templates

Comment: Everyone wants a different level of boilerplate, and you haven't specified the criteria well enough to get a suitable answer.